# Движение объекта в WindowsForms

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Осуществить движение квадрата по заданной прямой вперёд-назад.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    int x, Tempo;
    int N = 4;
    PointF point1 = PointF(20, 160);
    PointF point2 = PointF(70, 160);
    PointF point3 = PointF(70, 210);
    PointF point4 = PointF(20, 210);
    Graphics ^g = pictureBox1->CreateGraphics();
    g->Clear(System::Drawing::Color::White);
    Pen ^myPen = gcnew Pen(System::Drawing::Color::BlueViolet, 3);
    g->DrawLine(myPen, 20, 220, 340, 220);
    array <PointF> ^PointsXY = { point1, point2, point3,point4 };
    g->DrawPolygon(myPen, PointsXY);
    Tempo = (int)this->numericUpDown1->Value;
    if (!Tempo)
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Скорость не может быть равна нулю!");
            return;
    }
    for (x = 15; x < 350; x++)
    {
        g->Clear(System::Drawing::Color::White);
        g->DrawPolygon(myPen, PointsXY);
        _sleep(10);
    }
    for (x = 350; x>0; x--)
    {
        g->Clear(System::Drawing::Color::White);
        g->DrawPolygon(myPen, PointsXY);
        _sleep(10);
    }
    g->DrawLine(myPen, 20, 220, 340, 220);
}
```

Comment: Если вы новичок в программировании, я бы не советовал вам писать на C++/CLI, это слишком сложный и неудобный язык. Лучше пробовать на C#.

Comment: В UI-программировании не используется `sleep`, т. к. он блокирует отрисовку интерфейса. Используйте таймер.